# UIActivityViewController animation on iPad

Tags: ios, swift

Trying to get an UIActivityViewController to animate like in iOS Photos on iPad:

[image]

Code so far:

```
if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
            activityViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 540, height: 720)
            activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2 - 280, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height, width: 540, height: 720)
            activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = []
            }
viewController.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Checking for iPad and setting size and (final) position. That's how far I got. Tried adding an `UIView.animate` block to animate the view after it is being presented (changinging the initial position of course). Also tried creating a CATransition with `activityViewController.view.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)`. No success.

Comment: Isn't this a form sheet presentation style rather than a popover? And maybe set `modalTransitionStyle = .coverVertical`

Comment: As far as I know, `modalTransitionStyle` only works on iPhone. If I remove the popover code nothing will show up on iPad at all.